# Need help writing a batch file to manipulate file names into csv format

Tags: csv, batch-file

Currently I have a large number (about 10000) of images in a directory (no subfolders), and I need to catalogue them in a csv file. The image filenames are laid out as below:

```
p000001_06.jpg
p000001_05.jpg
p000001_04.jpg
p000001_03.jpg
p000001_02.jpg
p000001_01.jpg
f000005_11.jpg
f000004_11.jpg
f000003_11.jpg
f000002_11.jpg
f000001_01.jpg
```

Taking the first image as an example, I would need to get it into the following 5-column format:

```
p000001_06.jpg,p000001_06,p,000001,06
```

I have put together the script for the first two columns (see below):

```
(for %%F in (*) do @echo "%%~nxF",%%~nF) >imageExport.csv
```

However, I have been floundering around trying to get the rest of it right. I'm pretty sure that it is to do with delimiters and tokens, and I have been tinkering and tinkering but am just not getting it. Would really appreciate the help, as it is not my area of expertise. I also need to work out how to add column headings, but if that confounds matters it's not pressing. Many thanks

Comment: If you really are doing this recursively over subfolders then I'd suggest you update the question to say so instead of saying 'a number in a directory'. If not get rid of the **/r** option.

Comment: Thanks @Compo. Have updated the question.

Comment: Can you use PowerShell? This would be very easy - just a `dir -Recurse | Select {your_specific format} | Export-Csv`. Export-Csv will write the column headings as well if you want...

Comment: Hi @RB. Will explore the Powershell option as well, as that looks quite interesting. I only shied away from looking at it, as I'm not sure that the client PC has it installed (it's an external company with external IT admin).

Comment: Use $PSVersionTable to find out what version is installed (assuming it is installed!) :-)

Comment: Thanks @RB. Will do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delimiters and tokens don't help here. But as your files all have a common format (`Xnnnnnn_nn.XXX`) you can use simple string substitution. Also adding a header is easy:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM create header:
echo filename,name,letter,number,whatever>imageExport.csv

(for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
  set name=%%~nF
  echo %%~nxF,%%~nF,!name:~0,1!,!name:~1,6!,!name:~8,2!
)) >>imageExport.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stephan, that worked a treat. Very much appreciated. I'm not sure I would have figured out that approach.